# Folder and file explanation of newly created Flutter App?

Tags: file, flutter, directory, cross-platform, mobile-application

When I created a new app by running below command:

```
flutter create app_name
```

After creating app we found some folders and files(.idea, Android, build, ios etc) which already created. Can any one explain these files and folder in detail.

Answer (score 1):

.idea -> is settings from ur IDE, for example adding words to dictionary so they are now shown as a worning. (don't touch)

build -> when u build the app some generated code will be there (don't touch)

android -> your android app, when building an APK/AAB to upload to the store you can open it and generate the APK from there with android studio

ios -> your ios app, when uploading the app to the appstore u will need it

lib -> where all ur dart code should be

files:

pubspec.yaml -> all ur dependencies and all the global settings (fonts, assets, ...)